# Compute the angle between two vectors if two equations are known

Tags: vectors

I need to solve the following problem. Which approach should I use ? Is there any simple procedure for such problem ?

Determine the angle between vectors $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ if:
$(\vec{a} + 3\vec{b}) \perp (7\vec{a} - 5\vec{b})$ 
 and 
 
$(\vec{a} - 4\vec{b}) \perp (7\vec{a} - 2\vec{b})$

Answer (score 1):

Perpendicular means that the dot product is 0. So expanding we get two equations relating a.b to a^2 and b^2. A little manipulation give that a^2=b^2 and a.b = (1/2) b^2. In other words, the vectors are the same length. But a.b = a b cos k, where k is the angle between them, so cos k = 0.5 and hence k = 60 degrees.

Comment: great ! thanks very much.

Comment: @almagest I don't follow. Would you expand your answer to clarify how you get $a^2=b^2$?